# Nautilus crash error after login. (18.10, 64 bit)

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, crash, 18.10

Every time I log into my Ryzen 3 HP Laptop, the "Report a problem" dialogue shows. The error message is as follows.

> Sorry, Ubuntu 18.10 has experienced an internal error.
>   ▼ ExecutablePath
>      /usr/bin/nautilus
>   ▼ Package
>      nautilus 1:3.30.0-0ubuntu1~cosmic1 [origin: LP-PPA-gnome3-team-gnome3-staging]
>   ▼ProblemType
>       Crash
>   ▼Title
>    nautilus crashed with signal 5 in g_initable_new_valist()

There's more of course, but it's quite a large output, so I'm not going to type the whole thing here. If you need specific lines, just ask. 
     Could you please tell me how to stop this? Nautilus won't launch, and it is quite annoying.

Also, if I try to open it from the command-line, I get this:

> (nautilus:16566): Tracker-ERROR **: 19:14:27.855: Unable to find default domain ontology rule /usr/share/tracker/domain-ontologies/default.rule
>   Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the Nautilus package in the gnome-staging PPA at the moment. A hint is that it's looking for things in `/usr/share/tracker`, installing the Gnome filesystem index tracker (https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/) from the PPA will fix this:

```
apt install tracker
```

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=909375 for some details and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed Nautilus 3.30 from a source other than the normal Ubuntu repositories. Uninstall the nautilus files from `LP-PPA-gnome3-team-gnome3-staging`, disable this PPA, update the software libraries, and reinstall the Nautilus files native to 18.10 cosmic.

Comment: that threw some errors during install, but I fiddled with it until it worked. However, now sometimes when I type "nautilus" into terminal, it gives a runtime error in triplicate. Only rarely though, and I can't find any correlation between each occurrence. Any idea what that's about? (Next time it happens I'll be sure to post the exact output here."

Comment: @AlexLucas  You continue to run with an unsupported version of Nautilus... and "fiddled" it to get it to kinda work. Any problem with following my answer to solve your problem?

Comment: The solution you gave didn't work. Basically said that there was a problem with the package, and it couldn't install, so I added the ppa back, and now I've fixed the occasional runtime error. Nautilus now runs fine, but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @AlexLucas How did you fix the runtime errors? You could try running `sudo debsum -s` and see where your system stands.